# Is there a term for a list for which each member has a superscripted index that provides more detail?

Tags: vocabulary

The term "footnoted list" doesn't seem quite right here, especially because the notes don't appear at the bottom of the page:

Alex Holcombe<sup>1</sup>, John Smith<sup>2</sup>, Liqiang Wang<sup>3</sup>

<sup>1</sup>University of Sydney, <sup>2</sup>Ashland University, <sup>3</sup>Eotvos Lorand University

Comment: They're still called footnotes even when they're shown in a different place online.

Comment: You could call it an annotated list.